# I need a query to measure network bandwidth utilization in Azure using KQL

Tags: azure, bandwidth, azure-data-explorer

To start, I am new to KQL.  I am trying to write a query that provides me with an overall network utilization of my VM's.

Below is what I have currently:

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Network Interface"
| where Computer startswith "T1"
| where CounterPath contains "Bytes Received"or
    CounterPath contains "Current Bandwidth"
| project Computer, ObjectName, CounterName, CounterValue, CounterPath
| sort by Computer
| summarize avg(CounterValue) by Computer, CounterName
```

and it returns the two rows of data for each computer (one row for Bytes Received and one row for Current Bandwidth)

What I need to accomplish is combine the two rows of data for each computer with the equation `((Total Bytes\Sec * 8)/current bandwidth) * 100` - and this should produce a single data point for each computer.

Can someone help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

you could try using the [`avgif()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/avgif-aggfunction). for example:

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Network Interface"
| where Computer startswith "T1"
| where CounterPath has "Bytes Received" or CounterPath has "Current Bandwidth"
| summarize avg_BytesReceived = avgif(CounterValue, CounterPath has "Bytes Received"),
            avg_CurrentBandwidth = avgif(CounterValue, CounterPath has "Current Bandwidth")
         by Computer
| project Computer, Result = 100.0 * avg_BytesReceived * 8 / avg_CurrentBandwidth
```